# ARR module related error logged in 'Event Viewer'

Tags: windows, server, sitecore, iis-8, web-farm-framework

We have an issue on the production site and it throws 500 error. When I checked the 'Event Viewer', I saw the below error logged:-

The description for Event ID 11 from source Microsoft-Windows-IIS-IISManager cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

```
IISMANAGER_MODULE_INITIALIZATION_THREW_EXCEPTION

The Initialize method for module "Microsoft.Web.Management.WebFarm.WebFarmModule, Microsoft.Web.Management.WebFarmClient, Version=7.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" of type "WebFarmFramework" threw an exception.

Exception:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'Microsoft.Web.Management.WebFarmClient.resources'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Web.Management.WebFarm.WebFarmModule.Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
   at Microsoft.Web.Management.Client.Connection.Initialize(WebManagementInfo webManagementInfo)

Process:InetMgr
```

The version details are:-
IIS versoin 8.5.9600
ARR 3.0.1750
WebFarm Framework: 1.1.0490

I tried re-installing the ARR module on the server but I do not see the 'Server Farms' node in IIS even after installation.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you

Comment: After installing the ARR module you need to restart the IIS Mgr console

Comment: It might be better to just remove the WebFarmModule from your list of modules if you aren't using the features anyway

Comment: @RichardHauer : Thanks for the reply. Not only IIS but we actually restarted the server. But it didn't help.

Comment: @RichardHauer : It is getting used in the code so we actually couldn't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The exception seems to imply that the module hasn't been properly installed.  You can install it via the Web Platform Installer, or if your Installer had become corrupt, locate the file on a known good installation and copy it over.

From memory the module is located in C:\windows\system32\inetsrv